Черный экран при входе в Bios
У меня ноутбук Acer Aspire 7. Переустановил себе полностью с нуля Windows, через загрузочную флешку с выбором носителя в биосе. После чего решил установить себе вторую систему Arch Linux. После установки всё работает, но в Линукс приходится заходить через boot menu, оно работает, т.к. не могу поставить приоритет загрузки. По стандарту запускается Windows. Если кто-то стыкался с подобной проблемой или кто-то знает, как исправить данную проблему, прошу, помогите.

Тема вопроса не совсем соответствует тексту в описании, уточните проблему.
